# Error al reproducir audio

Tags: visual-studio

En mi pagina web sale los controles de música, pero no sale la música, que hago, ya intente ponerlo en loop y poner otros archivos pero no funciona. ¿Me podrían indicar que puedo hacer?

```
<audio src="WhatsApp Audio 2021-11-30 at 10.56.15 PM.mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
<audio src="cancion de spiderman.mp3" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></audio>
```

Comment: Que [lenguaje](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n) es? Visual Studio es un [IDE](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entorno_de_desarrollo_integrado)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola @Ramses el problema es el nombre del archivo con los espacios.
En html los espacios tienen un código prueba de ponerlo en toda una línea como te pongo a continuación:

```
<html>
    <audio src="WhatsApp_Audio_2021_11_30_at_10.56.15 PM.mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
    <audio src="cancion_de_spiderman.mp3" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></audio>
```

Comment: no aun asi no quiere reproducir lacancion, no sera el problema el nombre de la cancion

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no estás usando bien la etiqueta audio. Los archivos van en una subetiqueta source. Prueba así:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="WhatsApp Audio 2021-11-30 at 10.56.15 PM.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<audio autoplay loop>
    <source src="cancion de spiderman.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Y asegúrate de que los archivos mp3 están en el raiz de la web, si no, tienes que incluir la ruta en src.